# clr hosting in c++- path of assemblies

Tags: c++, c#-4.0

hi
i have created a c++ class to host .net4.0 assemblies in c++ applications.
the application that loads my c++ dll is the snmp service and the exe search the .net assembly under the system32 folder. i have tried with m_spDefaultAppDomain->AppendPrivatePath(...) but without sucess, is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

If the AppDomain has already been created, you can't change its private path AFAIK.

You can use an app.config file with the private probing path configuration element defined. Alternatively, you can sign your assemblies and store them in the GAC, so the CLR loader can find them regardless of the current directory.